# calling java script function from native iOS

Tags: javascript, ios7, uiwebview

I am looking for the possibility of calling the Java Script function from native iOS.

Generally we prefer the below method which could be used to call JS function from iOS.

```
NSString *returnvalue = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"your javascript code string here"];
```

But, in my case I need to call the function name as jsObject.FunctionName() like this.

```
NSString *returnvalue = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"jsObject.FunctionName()"];
```

Any idea, could be appreciated.

EDITED:

IDEA :
What we are trying to do is, instead of calling first method and keeping global variable for the reference in Java Script side, We can call the function w.r.t to each object.

Comment: @trojanfoe..yes, it is not working.

Comment: Have you ensured the page has finished loading before running that code?

Comment: Yes...but my point is that, the call which i am trying is correct or not? and what could be the case if page is loading?

Comment: Without seeing the code (including the javascript) it would be impossible to say if it's correct or not.

Answer (score 0):

Java script code calling through iOS

1. Through Javascript core Engine.
2. Through Web view

In first technique,

You will create a JSContext against .JS file
then you will use keyedScript for method calling and then call function will trigger that JS method.

Follow Raywenderlich for detailed help.
https://www.raywenderlich.com/1227-javascriptcore-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started

No Experience of second Web View JS technique.